# Husqvarna 125b Leaf Blower not running correctly

Tags: blower

It only has a few hours on it and may have been stored for an extended time with fuel mix in it.  It starts quickly but when I give it full throttle it bogs down.  If I pump the throttle lever it seems to run better.  See video for details. https://youtu.be/V9IC5inkru8

Here is the disassembled card[image]

Comment: you did not ask a question

Comment: What have you already done to remedy? New/clean air filter, dump all fuel and replace with fresh, check for fouled spark plug...?

Comment: Why is it running this way and how can I make it run normal

Comment: I have tried fresh gas. The air filter looks like new I will check the plug

Comment: I have disassembled the carb 2 time and cleaned it the best I could.  I took out the little mesh filter and cleaned that.  It had some goo in it.

Comment: When I first disassembled it the fluid in it did not smell like either gas or oil.  It had a strong chemical smell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

> may have been stored for an extended time with fuel mix in it

These sorts of engines are VERY sensitive to storage with Ethanol-containing fuel in them.  Your carburetor is almost certainly damaged or clogged and needs to be replaced or cleaned and rebuilt.

Do not EVER store such equipment without draining the fuel first and I've found it helpful use use E0 fuel (i.e. 0% Ethanol content) at all times.  You can buy this at most home centers and hardware stores (See "TruFuel" or similar) brands or at gas retailers such as marinas and Farm Bureau Coops that sell E0 gasoline.

Comment: I will try pulling the carb off and if I can't clean it I will buy a new one.  Is it ok to store non ethanol fuel in it?  Do people use 50:1 ratio?

Comment: It's best to store it drained of all fuel but E0 (i.e. non-ethanol) has a longer shelf-life then E10.  The Ethanol absorbs water from the air and that causes  the solution to separate.  The Ethanol/water mix settles to the bottom and is very corrosive and forms a hard varnish over time.  Don't guess on the ratio of fuel to oil.  Use EXACTLY what the manufacturer of the engine calls for.  50:1 is common but by no means the only possible mix.  I have a 50:1 but also a 40:1 and a 24:1.  Using the wrong mixture will damage the engine.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to clean it?   Carb cleaner, wire.  I don’t have  access to compressed air

Comment: The fact that fuel clogs carbs during storage has nothing to do with ethanol. It's a matter of residue left when the fuel dries out of small passages.

Comment: I'd try running a dose of Seafoam through the fuel. That has spared me a carb teardown on a few occasions. Otherwise, disassemble, soak, scrub, reassemble. Keep track of jet settings as you do.

Comment: Any suggestions on what to soak it in?

Comment: It's been my experience that no amount of soaking or running products through the tank will resolve this issue.  The plastic and metal parts in the carburetor are damaged and need to be replaced.  But you can try it.  Seafoam, acetone, brake fluid, carb cleaner, WD-40, etc. can all be tried.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out what the problem was.  The carb kits came with a new spark plug so I replaced it at the same time as the carb.  Apparently the plug was bad because when I put the old one back it it ran great!  Problem solved.  Thanks for all the suggestions.